# Is there a way to use SuiteQL to create a saved search?

Tags: netsuite, saved-searches, suiteql

The subject is pretty much my entire question.

I've got a SuiteQL query that I'd like to have sent to me each day.  I've confirmed that the query runs as a POST via the REST API without error.  Is there a way to take this query and create a saved search that I can schedule to have sent to me daily?

Thanks, in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a scheduled script that runs the SuiteQL, assembles the results and emails them to you.

If you haven't use the `N/query` module yet this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72855167/how-to-get-all-the-effective-currency-exchange-rate-by-date-in-netsuite-one-time) shows how to run SuiteQL in a script context with the results being pulled two different ways.

Comment: Thank you for this.  I've got the query saved as a script using the post you provided as a template.
I get so lost trying to get things done in Netsuite, compared to any other system I've used. 
 How do I attach this to a saved search to see the results?

Comment: You don't attach this to a saved search. Your original post mentioned sending it to you. You can either process and format the results as a CSV that you attach to your email or process the results as a table embedded in the html body of your email